# faster spell correction in text preprocessing

Tags: python, nlp, spell-checking

While working on text data, I applied Python code for spell correction in different ways as below.

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
import re

spell = SpellChecker()

def spell_correct(x):
   for w in spell.unknown(x.split()):
       x=re.sub(w,spell.correction(w),x)
   return x


df['twitts'] = df['twitts'].apply(lambda x :spell_correct(x))
```

and another way which i tried is:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
df['twitts'] = df['twitts'].apply(lambda x :TextBlob(x).correct())
```

Both python code mentioned above are taking incredibly heavy time to execute the code for 30000 lines of data in df. ( actually execution has to be stopped manually).

If someone know the trick to get the spell check in more efficient way, please share or comment.

Comment: Do you see the same unknown words multiple times?

Comment: Thank you for helping @tripleee. No actually, unknown words are not repeating. `spell.unknown('I am gooing to gooing to restzarant .. restzarant'.split())`  and the result for it is- **{'gooing', 'restzarant'}**

Comment: Sure, but if repeated `x` contain some of the same words, you could perhaps optimize that out.

Comment: Yeah sure, will check this out. But even TextBlob eats lot of time, .. i thought i am missing some important point... will update the optimized code.